# c3.js How do I read max and min axis values?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I like the auto scaling for the y axis offered in c3, but I would like to be able to retrieve the max and min values that it chooses.  In my case, I would like a Celsius scale on the y axis and and equivalent Fahrenheit scale on y2. It seems like

```
console.log(chart.axis.range());
console.log(chart.axis.max());
```

should produce (on the console log) the numbers that I would like, so that I can convert them to Fahrenheit and produce a y2 scale.  Unfortunately, I get undefined values.

```
{x: undefined, y: undefined, y2: undefined}
x: undefined
y: undefined
y2: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

If I have previously set the max or the min values for the axis, then they are defined, but I would like the autoscale values.

I would prefer to not use a workaround where I scan the y values of the data for a max and min and then calculate my own no-longer-autoscale values.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me to get the mins and maxes:

```
   // First make sure that they are defined, otherwise
   // they can show up as undefined.
   chart.axis.range({max: {x: 4, y: 5}, min: {x: 2, y: 3}});

   var axis = chart.axis;  // Shorthand. reference to axis.
   // display them:
   console.log(
       "    x min: " + axis.min()['x'] +
       "    x max: " + axis.max()['x'] +
       "    y min: " + axis.min()['y'] +
       "    y max: " + axis.max()['y']
   );
```